# Need to swap two elements in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, max, min

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Swap {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many integers? ");
        int size = kb.nextInt();

        int[] values = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter integers:");

        for (int i = 0;i < size; i++){
            values[i] = kb.nextInt();
        }
        int min = values[0];
        for(int i = 0;i < values.length;i++){
            if(values[i] < min){
                min = values[i];
            }
        }
        int max = values[0];
        for(int i = 0;i < values.length;i++){
            if(values[i] > max){
                max = values[i];
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I am just getting caught up on a small thing: I don't know how to extract the location of the min and max, as in the index of them in order to swap them. I originally tried something along the lines of values[min] but I guess java doesn't hold your hand that much which is understandable

Comment: `min and max` would be the actual values... you would need to save the `i` variable in each of those loops to swap them. such as `minIndex = i`  and `maxIndex = i`. Where your values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you store in `min` and `max` the result of a calculation. From OOD this is bad because values in the array can change meanwhile and gives you an invalid state.

Instead of min and max you should store the minIndex and maxIndex. A loop might look like this:

```
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < values.length;i++){
        if(values[i] > values[maxIndex]){
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
```

Now it is easy to swap them:

```
int tmp = values[maxIndex];
values[maxIndex]=values[minIndex];
values[minIndex]=tmp;
```